# Insufficient file permissions in OneDrive

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, file-permissions, onedrive

I installed OneDrive, but my system has insufficient file permissions to write to OneDrive. For instance, when I want to install Laravel, I use the command `laravel new`, but I get the error `Failed to open stream: Permission denied.`

It doesn't matter which folder I try, but as soon as I try it outside Onedrive, it works. The same is for any other script that wants to write to the Onedrive folder.

I am using a Windows 10 machine, and I already have full user permissions on the Onedrive folder. How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that Bitdefender AntiVirus was the problem. I went to Application Access (under the Safe Files settings), and gave permissions to Apache and PHP CLI. Now it works.

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528273/running-php-files-stored-on-onedrive)

Comment: what version of BitDefender were you using?

Comment: Bitdefender Antivirus Plus 2018